# Project Euler #35: nicer way to test if an even integer is 'inside' an integer

Tags: python

Question: What's the best way to iterate over an integer and find other integers inside it, then throw that integer away if it contains them?

Long Version:

I have been working on my Python skills by trying to make efficient solutions to the problems at Project Euler. After going through around 20 problems, I find that while I can solve the problems my solutions are often inelegant and clunky (i.e., ugly and slow). The way the problems are structured, I think I need to learn some better solutions because more complex stuff is going to compound these inefficiencies.

Anyway, today I'm working on problem 35, which requests all circular primes below 1,000,000. I have produced a list of all primes below 1,000,000 and I built a little framework to spit out permutations of these primes below, for each of which I was planning to test for prime-ness:

```
def number_switcher(number):
  number = [num for num in str(number)]
  numlist = [''.join(num) for num in list(itertools.permutations(number))]
  return [int(num) for num in numlist]
```

Running this on **all** the primes and then testing each possible permutation for prime-ness, as you can imagine, is no way to solve the problem.

Then it occurred to me that I could throw away all numbers that have an even number in them (assuming they're longer than one digit) or any numbers with fives in them before I even start running the permutations.

Here's where I really got lost. Even though it seems simple, I can't figure out after two days of trying, how to throw away any multi-digit number with an even number or a 5 inside of it.

Here's what I tried (assuming a list of all primes below 1,000,000 called here "primes"):

```
 [num for num in primes if any(x for x in '024685' in str(num))] # failed: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Then I experimented with the following:

```
for prime in primes:
  if '0' in str(prime):
    primes.remove(prime)

>>>>len(primes)
4264
```

This cut my primes list about in half. Okay, so maybe I'm on the right track and I just need an ugly "if '0' in str(prime) or if '2' in str(prime)," etc.

But here's the weird thing: when I examine my 'primes' list, it still has primes with '0's in it. Running the same thing again on the new list of primes, I get the following results:

```
 for prime in primes:
   if '0' in str(prime):
     primes.remove(prime)
>>>>len(primes)
4026
```

...and again the result drops to:

```
>>>>len(primes)
3892
....
3861 # again
....
3843 #and again
```

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here, but it seemed like that first if-test should find any prime with '0' in it and remove all of them?

Lastly, I also tried the following, which seems terrible because it jumps pointlessly back and forth across the str-integer train tracks, but it seemed like it just had to work:

```
for num in primes:
  for d in str(num):
    if (int(d) % 2 == 0 or int(d) == 5):
      primes.remove(num)   # doesn't work: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list 
    else:
      pass
```

I feel like I shouldn't be tearing my hair out over this question, but it's making me a little crazy and probably because I've gotten to a point where I'm just trying to hack out a solution, my attempts are getting less lucid.

Here's my question:

What's the best way to iterate over an integer and find other integers inside it, then throw that stupid integer away if it contains them?

Thanks for your help/reading.

Footnote:
This is the first question I have asked here but I have benefitted from this site's guidance for a few months now. Apologies if this question/solution is extant, but I looked for it and could not find a way to cobble together a solution. Most search results come up as "how to tell if an integer is even".

Comment: Might want to include a link to the problem itself: http://projecteuler.net/problem=35

Comment: Just saying, you might be a bit off in your prime-calculation. My method (using the Sieve of Eratosthenes) gives me about 77k primes (or something around that, something over 70k) for 0-1000000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@root is correct that your assumption about how to optimise this is false, but I'd thought it'd be useful to point out why what you're doing isn't working on a Python level.

**Your bool problem**:

```
[num for num in primes if any(x for x in '024685' in str(num))] # failed: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

`'024685' in str(num)` is being evaluated first, so it equates to `for x in True` - which isn't possible. The above would be written as:

```
[num for num in primes if not any(ch in '024685' for ch in str(num)]
```

Which takes each character from `str(num)` and checks to see if it's one of `'024685'`.

**Your list problem**:

There's a rule of thumb here - *don't modify something you're iterating over*. If you were to try this with a `dict` you'd get an exception thrown  - but for a `list` it's likely to get *silently wrong*, but occasionally will break.

When removing more than one value from a list, it's better to build a new list keeping only the required values, eg:

```
no_zero = [num for num in primes if '0' not in str(num)]
```

And if you wanted to modify the original primes:

```
primes[:] = no_zero
```

Your last example also fails because of `.remove()`, and putting the above together can be written as:

```
[num for num in primes if not any(num % i == 0 for i in (2, 5)]
```

**Misc**:

You may wish to consider storing the primes in a `set` - as you're not concerned about the order of the primes, and will be faster for membership testing.

Comment: His optimization is actually correct, in this case. Project Euler #35 asks for prime numbers where each of their permutations are also prime. Ie: 29 wouldn't count because 92 is not prime. Otherwise great answer.

Comment: @ChimeraObscura Your comment makes perfect sense - thanks for correction (I will admit it's been a while since I looked at #35 though...)

Comment: This works nicely. Thanks for the help and the descriptive answer. You had me worried for a moment with my optimization, but then I realized that I didn't stress enough that I'm working with circular primes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Jon Clements. I was able to solve the problem today with the following script (note that I had to make sure the '024685' stripper did not strip out '2' and '5' because those were part of the answer, which threw me off for awhile...):

```
import math
import itertools

def prime_test(number):
  if all(number % x != 0 for x in range(2, int(math.sqrt(number)) + 1)):
    return True
  else:
return False

def find_primes(limit):
  primes = [2]
  for x in range(3, limit + 1, 2):
    if prime_test(x):
      primes.append(x)
    else:
      pass
  return primes

def circulate(number):
  circ_list = [number]
  x = 1
  while x < len(str(number)):
    number = str(number)[1:] + str(number)[0]
    circ_list.append(number)
    x += 1
  return circ_list

def main():
  primes = find_primes(1000000)
  no_evens = [x for x in primes if not any(ch in '024685' for ch in str(x) if len(str(x)) > 1)]

  circular_primes = [] 
  for prime in no_evens:
    if all(prime_test(x) for x in circulate(prime)):
      circular_primes.append(prime)
    else:
      pass

  return circular_primes, len(circular_primes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(main())
```

Another thing I didn't realize is that I was merely supposed to *rotate* the number, not provide all possible permutations of it. These gotches probably throw people off when they're trying to solve the problem.